# Flat all observables on window/buffer

Tags: rx-java

I´m trying to use window/buffer operator, but I end up with the same problem. Since buffer and window return an observable per emition, I end up having an `Observable<ArrayList<String>>` in my return, but I need a `List<Integer>`.

Any idea how to flat all those observables?

```
@Test
public void test() {
    Integer[] numbers = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
     Observable.from(numbers)
            .window(4)
            .flatMap(ns -> ns
                    .map(number -> "uniqueKey=" + number + "&")
                    .reduce("", String::concat))
            .map(query -> query.substring(0, query.length() - 1))
            .collect(ArrayList<String>::new, List::add); //-> Given an error since it´s an Observable<ArrayList<String>>

}
```

If I subscribe the observable and I add every element in an external list works, but it´s not the desirable.

```
.map(query -> query.substring(0, query.length() - 1))
            .subscribe(elements::add);
```

> ***UPDATE:***

Since I cannot remove the question, just confirm that the only way obviously to get the item emitted is by subscribe, or toBlocking.

I think I spend too much nowadays with Stream() palmface icon on!

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's expected behaviour since all operators return `Observable`. If you need to block until your code completes you can use `.toBlocking().first()`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but as I said in my answer, If I have to wait I would use subscribe, as far as I know use .toBlocking().first() it´s an anti pattern, that only on test scenario should be used.

Comment: If you want to receive a `List` you need either to `subscribe` to an `Observable` and get it in your `onNext()` or block. There's also `forEach` operator but you will need an external `List` since it returns void.